# Mysql-Python-Connector get columns names from select statement in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

i have a stored procedure that contains multiple statements simplified as below

```
create temp table...; 
update temp table...; 
....
select * from temp table; #last statement
```

I have below Python code to get return results from the SP. I need the column names so that I can convert the results into JSON format. However, cursor.description returns nothing I expect. Advise please!! Mysql5.7, mysql-python-connector 2.x by Oracle, python 3.5

```
cursor.callproc(proc, args)
columns = cursor.description
print(columns) #returns [('@_sp_get_toc_arg1', 8, None, None, None, None, 1, 128)]

for result in cursor.stored_results():
    return result.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iterator returned by `cursor.stored_results()` yields cursors, you'll need to inspect the description of those to get the column names, not of the initial cursor:

```
for result in cursor.stored_results():
    print(result.description)
    return result.fetchall()
```

Comment: hi, mata. what if i wanted to fetchall all results/data and not just column headers from pyodbc? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72209641/how-do-i-read-sql-stored-procedure-data-through-pyodbc-and-get-results-into-a-da

Answer (score 0):

## Simplest Way

Use the *next* build-in function:

```
columns = next(cursor.stored_results()).column_names
```

But I think the best approach when a **JSON format** is needed is to use a **dictionary-like cursor:**

```
dict_cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=True)
dict_cursor.callproc("proc")
results = next(dict_cursor.stored_results()).fetchall()
```

The *results* variable is a list that contains an object for each retrieved record with column names as keys `[{column_name: first_row_value, ...}, {column_name: second_row_value, ...}, ...]`